# using an Array to query an sqlite database android

Tags: android

how can i use an Array of strings to query an sqlite database? i keep getting the exception "SQliteException: bind or column index out of range".

```
      String[] names = new String[values.size()]; // values is an Arraylist
      String[] condition = values.toArray(names);
Cursor row = db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, resultColumns, NAME +"=" + "?", condition, null, null, null,null);
```

please any help will be greatly appreciated as usual. Thanks

P.S values, which is the Arraylist is being poplulated through a loop so i can't have a defined size. thats why i can't use the get() method and seperate the elements in it by commas' which would have been easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query's where clause is `where name = ?`. This expects the passed-in array to be of size 1. Judging by its name (names), I'm guessing its not. You need to rethink what you want your SQL query to be (maybe `where name in ...`).

E.g.:

```
final String whereClause = NAME + " in (" + convertToCommaDelimitedString(values) + ")"; 
db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, resultColumns, whereClause, null, null, null, null,null);
```

You need to implement `String convertToCommaDelimitedString(Collection c)`;

Comment: yes.. you are right, the array size is more than one. but am not too good with sqlite.. so i don't know how to call that method you suggested. could you please give me the syntax format or a link i can follow along?... thanks for the response

Comment: hi.. thanks for the response.. i already have my Arraylist seperated by commas, so i don't know if i need to implement it again.

Comment: tried it.. its now giving me another sqliteException "syntax error".. :(

Comment: sorry, i forgot to tick the answer. had to re-implement my logic for my app and not it works. thanks once again